# How to use the linking word "e.g.", meaning "for example"?

Tags: formatting

Talking from one field in the human sciences.

When giving examples in parentheses illustrating one notion ‘the subject agrees in number with the verb (e.g. "it belongs")’, or providing references from the literature ‘the sign "un" is an article (e.g. Grevisse & Goose 2008)’, can we not use the "e.g." linking word? Concretely, writing ‘(it belongs)’ instead of ‘(e.g. it belongs)` and (Grevisse & Goose 2008) instead of ‘(e.g. Grevisse & Goose 2008)’?

Comment: You should put a comma after e.g. ("online help sites, e.g., Academica Stack Exchange...").

Answer (score 2):

*e.g.* the contraction of the Latin *exempli gratia*, which translate to “for example”.  Thus the easy rule is to use it when you would use “for instance”.  I would use it in both of your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question which was not completely clear. Is it possible to not use "e.g."?

Comment: I get that, and I would not “not use it” in the examples you provided. In both instances it is much more natural to use “for instance”.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit repetitive maybe, but my manuscript is full of this kind of parentheses, and I feel having "e.g." is like overcharging. It does not matter?

Comment: It's fine in the uses you cited. Meanwhile a ton of people suffering from collective amnesia write "i.e." (*id est*, "that is") in the same place, when they in fact mean e.g., i.e., "for example". :)

Comment: In the uses you mentioned, "e.g." makes it clear that, though you've given only one example, there are others.